# Spring boot app shuts down when .jar is ran from .bat but not in IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that I can run in intellij taht will output this in the console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-08-08T17:25:17.341+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] vb.backend.BackendApplication            : Starting BackendApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 16720 (C:\Users\Acer\Documents\persoonlijk\code projects\VB\VB\UI\backend\target\classes started by Acer in C:\Users\Acer\Documents\persoonlijk\code projects\VB\VB\UI\backend)
2023-08-08T17:25:17.347+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] vb.backend.BackendApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-08T17:25:18.274+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-08T17:25:18.332+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 50 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-08T17:25:18.905+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-08-08T17:25:18.913+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-08T17:25:18.914+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-08-08T17:25:19.020+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-08T17:25:19.020+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1593 ms
2023-08-08T17:25:19.155+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-08-08T17:25:19.346+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:4639ca67-0856-41e0-a31a-90bc19b84a68 user=SA
2023-08-08T17:25:19.348+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-08-08T17:25:19.407+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-08-08T17:25:19.465+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-08-08T17:25:19.468+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-08-08T17:25:19.624+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-08T17:25:19.778+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-08-08T17:25:20.075+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-08-08T17:25:20.732+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-08-08T17:25:20.783+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-08T17:25:21.063+02:00  WARN 16720 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-08-08T17:25:21.447+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-08-08T17:25:21.457+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] vb.backend.BackendApplication            : Started BackendApplication in 4.707 seconds (process running for 5.719)
```

that I compiled into a .jar file that I'm trying to run from a .bat that looks like this:

```
@echo off
title UI-backend
cd "./backend"
java -jar backend.jar
```

which will start the app but shutdown immediatly after:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

17:29:27.440 [main] INFO vb.backend.BackendApplication -- Starting BackendApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 1108 (C:\Users\Acer\Documents\persoonlijk\code projects\VB\sample .bat setup\UI\backend\backend.jar started by Acer in C:\Users\Acer\Documents\persoonlijk\code projects\VB\sample .bat setup\UI\backend)
17:29:27.444 [main] INFO vb.backend.BackendApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
17:29:28.782 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
17:29:28.911 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 113 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
17:29:29.893 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Starting...
17:29:30.231 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -- HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:dd6687ab-bd2c-4d04-9404-b70533daadbf user=SA
17:29:30.234 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
17:29:30.365 [main] INFO org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper -- HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
17:29:30.462 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version -- HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING]
17:29:30.464 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment -- HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
17:29:30.717 [main] INFO org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator -- HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
17:29:30.853 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo -- No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
17:29:31.394 [main] INFO org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator -- HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
17:29:32.266 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator -- HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
17:29:32.328 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
17:29:33.232 [main] INFO vb.backend.BackendApplication -- Started BackendApplication in 6.119 seconds (process running for 6.504)
17:29:33.478 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
17:29:33.483 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
17:29:33.488 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Why does this happen, it's the exact same app ran from the same java SDK there should be no reason for the app to shut down yet it just does.

Comment: How do you build your jar file ? , if you are using maven, do it with `mvn package`  and retry. of course do it after clean

Comment: That indeed solves it, I was using IntelliJ IDEA's built in artifact builder to get a .jar before.